# Keep Gitlab repositories in sync with airgapped networks

Tags: gitlab

I have 3 networks (`network_1`, `network_2` and `network_3`). The three networks are airgapped.

On `network_1` I have a Gitlab instance.

I want to host an instance of Gitlab on `network_2` and on `network_3`. Which should be mirrors of the Gitlab instance from `network_1`.

I have a 4th network (`network_4`) where I can store files from `network_1` and download these files from  `network_2` and from `network_3`. Tunneling or proxying does not work through `network_4`.

One option I found is:

- Export repository/repositories on Gitlab instance on `network_1`.
- Transfer export file (through `network_4`) to `network_2` and `network_3`.
- Import the export file on `network_2` and `network_3`.

Downside is:

- Kinda slow. (Exporting takes times, transferring takes times, importing takes time).
- Cannot import if the project already exists, so every time I want to import the export file I need to delete the project first.
- Cannot import changes only, so every time I need to import the whole repository.

Any other options/solutions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a solution has been found and this is unlikely to help anyone else

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

On `network_1`:

Create Git repository from Gitlab project:

```
git clone /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/<path to project>.git /tmp/repository_name.git
```

Create Git bundle from Git repository:

```
cd /tmp/repository_name.git
git bundle create /tmp/repository_name.bundle --all
```

Transfer `/tmp/repository_name.bundle` to `network_2/3`.

On `network_2/3`:

Create Git repository from Git bundle:

```
git clone --bare /tmp/repository_name.bundle /tmp/repository_name.git
```

Set origin URL:

```
cd /tmp/repository_name.git
git remote set-url origin https://url-to-gitlab-on-network2-3/group/project.git
```

Push changes/content to Gitlab:

```
git push --mirror
```